# How to use USB camera in Android CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax, usb-camera

I am using Android cameraX with ImageAnalysis for face detection using ML-kit, But now I want to use USB camera instead of a front or back camera but cameraX provides only 2 options.

```
CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
```

Comment: if you could see the external camera, you could use CameraSelector.Builder.addCameraFilter() to select the external camera.

Comment: val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .addCameraFilter {
                it.filter { camInfo -> Camera2CameraInfo.from(camInfo).getCameraCharacteristic(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL }
            }.build()

Comment: @Gerry does it actually work? Afaik cameraX doesn't support usb cameras

Comment: There are code in it, not tested though. I did not get it detected when I was trying it.